# Return last index value from a match()

Tags: excel

I am working with time series data in Excel to communicate some calculations to our programmers. I am stuck trying to return the index location of the last max value in an array. I have been utilizing the match() function, as in cell D12:

=MATCH(C12,B2:B12,0)

This returns a value of 1 because 126.47 is duplicated at the locations of 1 and 7 in the array. What I really want to return is 7, the location of the last max value. I have looked into the index() and lookup() functions, but without success. Thank you for your help!

[image]

Edit 1: To clarify, the Match function does 90% of what I want to do, with the exception of these duplicates. Here is more data, to highlight my only error is with the duplicates:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are actually looking for is a pseudo-MAXIF function.

```
=MAX(INDEX(ROW($1:$11)*($B$2:$B$12=$C$12), , ))
```

That will return the row number (as the position within the range like a [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) would). To retrieve the date from columns A this would be,

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$12, MAX(INDEX(ROW($1:$11)*($B$2:$B$12=$C$12), , )))
```

Intermediate values (if there were more than two) could be retrieved using the [SMALL function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SMALL-function-4050a82e-659a-4ef6-a970-c963a6f69c29) or [LARGE function](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/large-function-3688ad91-0b0c-43db-8ef8-825a5e5871db) in place of the [MAX function](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/max-function-f7bec1eb-9c66-489a-9166-51d2c9d19333).

When transcribing for your own purposes, remember that `ROW(1:11)` is the *position within* B2:B12, not the actual row on the worksheet. The number being returned is analogous to the number being returned by a similar MATCH function.

**EDIT - Float last 11 values:**

To capture the last 11 values, the absolute row references should be removed from the column B and C cell range references.

```
=MAX(INDEX(ROW($1:$11)*(B2:B12=C12), , ))
```

[image: Float last 11 values]

Comment: The use of ROW here is not so rigorous. For example, what if the OP decides, for whatever reason, to move their data from B2:B12 to e.g. B4:B14? Your first formula will not give correct results. Will the OP necessarily know to what the ROW part needs amending? Even better, can you amend your construction so that it always returns correct answers, even if the range being queried is changed?

Comment: thanks @XORLX, i should have clarified, that i only provided a snippet of my data. i do indeed need to roll the function downward on the entire time-series.

Comment: @user1499626 That wasn't actually what I meant. Perhaps you can add something to your original post which clarifies this comment? Perhaps one or two more expected results?

Comment: @XORLX - Fair enough; I've added some narrative by way of explanation. I've also seen methods like `ROW(B2:B12)-ROW(B2)+1` but I see that as a bit hacky and shows no understanding of the concept of using `ROW` to generate a series of potential positions within B2:B12  that could be a match.

Comment: @Jeeped Can you clarify? "Hacky"? How does it show "no understanding of the concept of using ROW to generate a series of potential positions within B2:B12 that could be a match."? Constructions such as the one you give in your previous comment, as well as ROW(B2:B12)-MIN(ROW(B2:B12))+1, show MORE understanding, in my opinion, and don't suffer the drawbacks that I pointed out re your construction. Given a choice between a set-up which is unrigorous and which may require user input and one which is rigorous and requires none, why opt for the former?

Comment: @XORLX - I guess I prefer the OP understand the concept of using `ROW` rather than a turn-key formula that they do not understand. Of course, if they get that they are returning the relative position rather than a worksheet row number then they should be able to alter the formula to something like `ROW(2:12)-MIN(ROW(2:12))+1`. Before the concept is grasped using `ROW(2:12)-MIN(ROW(2:12))+1` only serves to onfuscate the nature of the formula further.

Comment: I can appreciate that philosophy, though would personally be hesitant to fully endorse it. Knowingly giving a sub-optimal solution with a view to enhancing the OP's learning is a noble intention, though also one not without drawbacks. However, we could go on, so I think best to leave this philosophical discussion to another time. Suffice to ask you what you would say if I were to offer the OP what is perhaps the best solution of all, involving LOOKUP with reciprocation of the array with unity? Far too "turn-key", I imagine?

Comment: @XORLX - The more the merrier! :) Be sure to lockdown half of the range references while allowing the others to 'float' as per the OP's expanded sample.

Comment: @Jeeped Didn't notice at first, but I can't help but point out the slight irony in your talk of understanding concepts and - which I've only just spotted - your circumventing the need for CSE by incorporating an additional INDEX function in your solution, which is probably one of the most complex, non-standard uses of any function in Excel. Try explaining that one to the OP! :-)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
=MAX(IF(C12=$B$2:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B)),ROW($B$2:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B)))))-1
```

You will need to array enter this with ctrl + shift + enter.

Comment: I think you will find that you are offset one row (returning actual row from B2:B12 rather than from 1:11.